# Simulate button click in Sharepoint 2010 using python 3.4 and requests library

Tags: asp.net, python-3.x, sharepoint-2010, python-requests, sharepoint-workflow

How to perform button click, named: "confirm", using python 3.x and requests library? What parameters should be passed with POST request.

In general i am interested how to guess what settings are needed to achieve my point.

Here are headers information from the browser network graph (with slightly modified values):

```
General

Request URL:SOMEURL
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:SOMEADDR



Response Headers

Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:203
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 20 Apr 2016 05:54:51 GMT
Location:SOMELOCATION
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices:14.0.0.6123
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid:04e5403d-3170-4c1d-a5a3-441776ca4e57
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
X-MS-InvokeApp:1; RequireReadOnly
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SharePointHealthScore:0



Request Headers

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ka;q=0.2
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:3836
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:filterValue=f4298401-b95c-4f84-b127-c1237f65819d; ASP.NET_SessionId=t35zomew310lpn45bgy1kp55; SectionId=15; databaseBtnText=0; databaseBtnDesc=0; Ribbon.ListItem=1366667|-1|655|1597680975; stsSyncAppName=Client; stsSyncIconPath=; Ribbon.ListForm.Display=808667|-1|503|815204513
Host:HOST
Origin:ORIGIN
Referer:REFERER
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36



Query String Parameters

itemID:ID
List:LIST
activity:ACTION
workflowID:WFID
source:SOURCE



Form Data

MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource:
MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId:
MSOTlPn_View:0
MSOTlPn_ShowSettings:False
MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary:
MSOGallery_FilterString:
MSOTlPn_Button:none
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName:Browse
MSOSPWebPartManager_ExitingDesignMode:false
MSOWebPartPage_Shared:
MSOLayout_LayoutChanges:
MSOLayout_InDesignMode:
MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName:Browse
MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName:false
MSOSPWebPartManager_EndWebPartEditing:false
_maintainWorkspaceScrollPosition:0
__REQUESTDIGEST:0x2D3C5B3A042C327D5B676EA782F2AB9623C1E03DD32F9884204134C32E8EB4287AB98B49EB235D3E27D0F8C0870E3F1CE69ABCDC2AB9C3797023D74CC1DC9AA9,20 Apr 2016 05:53:06 -0000
__VIEWSTATE:REMOVED
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:REMOVED
InputKeywords:Search this site...
ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$ctl03:0
ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$hiddRedirectURL:
ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$hidConfirm:checked
ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$hiddValidate:
ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$Button2:Confirm
__spText1:
__spText2:
```

Comment: You're trying to click a button via a POST request? You might want to consider ditching the button click and using either [SharePoint's REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) or its other available [web services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: No i definitely want to simulate click via python-requests. I can't guess what headers and parameters should be passed while posting in order to get desired result. If you know how to do that, would be grateful.

Comment: @Thriggle someone help me :(

Comment: What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve? Clicking a button on a web page is a client side action that cannot be done through an http request; you might be able to mimic the outcome of a button click (such as if clicking the button itself triggers a POST request) but we don't have enough information from your question to guess what the button does.